# tf.nn.static_rnn gives different sizes of output compared to input

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement LSTM nets using tensorflow.

and i have a LSTMcell with the number of units = 4.

`cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(4, state_is_tuple=True)`

and my input is a **`2 X 44`**(data_hold) matrix, which i split into 4.

`inputs_series = tf.split(data_hold, 4, axis=1)`

so, each unit must be of size 2 X 11 right?

when i check my input series it is a list of tensors of shape **`2 X 11`** as expected.

```
[<tf.Tensor 'split:0' shape=(2, 11) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:1' shape=(2, 11) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:2' shape=(2, 11) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:3' shape=(2, 11) dtype=float32>]
```

but when i check the **`state_series`**, it is a list of tensors of shape **`2 X 4`**.

```
# initial_state is initial_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(state_data_hold, hidden_data_hold)
state_series, current_step = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=inputs_series, initial_state=initial_state)


 # state_series
[<tf.Tensor 'rnn/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'rnn/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/mul_5:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'rnn/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/mul_8:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'rnn/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/mul_11:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32>]
```

my question is that shouldn't the shape of the state series and the input series be same ?

> As per the docs of static_rnn Returns: A pair (outputs, state) where:
>
> outputs is a length T list of outputs (one for each input), or a
>   nested tuple of such elements. state is the final state

and when i print current_step it returns a tuple of current and hidden unit, but which unit to be specific? (there are 4 right?)

any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't the shape of the state series and the input series be same

I don't understand why you would expect that. The state shape depends on the cell, not on its input. The shape of all RNN-like cells are determined by its `state_size` attribute, and for `BasicLSTMCell`, it is a tuple of two tensors of shape `[num_units]`.

Comment: yea, thanks my bad i figured it out, actually i got confused between state_size and number of inputs by splitting the loaded data. but for the second part of my question that there is a tuple for each batch, suppose i have 11 batches being fed into the ltmsnet, and for each batch there is a hidden unit and a current unit, so in total there are 11 tuples, right? so when i print the current state it gives me the tuple of last batch right?